# WidgetKit: Feedback on whether or not/when a TimelineEntry was shown

Tags: ios, swiftui, widgetkit

I have an app with a widget and I would like to rotate the content based on what was last shown in the widget. In other words, if a `TimelineEntry` is rendered and displayed to the users, I'd like some sort of feedback or callback. Or another possibility would be to just run code eg in `onAppear` but that does not seem to work, does it?

How would I get my main app to learn which `TimelineEntry`s were shown and which were not?

Comment: You can’t, this is impossible.